# How do you automatically create .js files using AJAX or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Is there a way to create a .js file using PHP or AJAX on a form submit?

I have a short form that the user inputs tracking ID's into, when the form is submitted the IDs are saved into a mysql database.

At the same time as the form is submitted i want to automatically create a .js file that will be called the same as the submitted ID.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: file_put_contents(); is one way. but it does seem like an odd idea.

Comment: I'm trying to create a "conversion tag CMS". So I will be able to create my tags using Google Doubleclick and then input the IDS into my CMS. I then have to just give the Advertiser a simple .js call in link so I don't have to keep going back to them if I need to make any changes to the conversion tags. Any changes i can do at my end.

Comment: JavaScript files can be generated exactly the same as HTML files in PHP.  So you can have http://x.y.z/script.php?id=1234 without having to create a file for every ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here check this function in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Call it in the page called in your submit